# Change node title on search results in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

In drupal 7 I want to change the node title for my search results.

The reason for this is because when the search results are viewed. The current page title in breadcrumbs is set to "content". I wish to change this to my own specific title.

Please can someone help me with this it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, you can use this in your theme's template.php:

```
function hook_preprocess_search_result(&$variables)
```

It works for me.